# idealTree:example.js: sill idealTree buildDeps

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, npm-install, enoent

i have run a command npm install mongodb and it stuck on these
idealTree:example.js: sill idealTree buildDeps

after some time i will get an error which is
npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! network request to http://registry.npmjs.org/mongodb failed, reason:
getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND your-proxy-server
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2024-01-25T18_18_49_879Z-debug-0.log

and anything command related to npm install is not working
what to do i have stuck on above for 3 days?

what i did:-

1. i have try on another mern stack project no npm install command is working on any mern stack project.
2. try to disable ipv6 but these is the main ethernet connection by which i am connecting internet.
3. i have try to delete node module and then again try but not getting any result.
4. i delete my nodejs and reinstall my nodejs application and then reinstall npm but not getting executed.